# What are recommended places in Ireland to photograph?

Tags: locations

I am going on a short photo trip to Ireland next March and plan to stay for 4 days. I rent a car and want to visit great photo places in Ireland.

What places can you recommend going to and at what time of day?

Comment: Before voting to close this as "too localized", please read http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/1232/1943. And, Merry Christmas, everyone!

Comment: I usually search on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=ireland&s=int) for interesting places near a location. And use [TPE](http://photoephemeris.com/) to get an idea of light direction etc.

Comment: @mattdm I would suggest moving it to the travel stackexchange site.

Comment: @ab.aditya: I wasn't aware of a Travel Stackexchange Site. I guess this question would fit there better.

Comment: @juergen d: There are quite a bunch of stackexchange sites - new ones come up every now and then :-). One of the moderators should be able to help you move the question over to the travel sites.

Comment: @ab.aditya — not a bad idea. We should ask on their meta site if they want these questions and if so migrate them there.

Comment: My wife and I recently spent 9 days bike touring in the Connemara and Burren areas around Galway. Here are the photos I took:
https://picasaweb.google.com/101971452775781176008/Ireland
They should give you a feel for the terrain of the central West coast. If you have any questions about specific locations where the shots were taken I can probably answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to an iPad, Trey Ratcliff of Stuck in Customs has a free app called [Stuck on Earth](http://www.stuckonearthapp.com/).  This uses crowdsourcing to choose popular locations and photos.  Like Google Earth/Maps, you can zoom in on locations, and with the app, click on spots and view photos taken there.

You can take Shane's advice, have a look at south west Ireland, and then click through images to help choose specific locations you want to visit.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the south west of the country and head for Kerry, specifically Dingle and continue west and drive around the peninsula. There's some amazing views there. It won't be great if it's a bad day though!